# Unable to deploy in Netbeans 6.7.1 and Glassfish v2.1.1

Tags: java, windows-7, netbeans6.7, glassfish-esb

I am trying to deploy a simple WebService in Netbeans 6.7.1 and Glassfish v2.1.1 and am getting the following error. I am using GlassfishESBv2.2 and windows 7 machine. I have tried googling and implemented things as shown in
http://forums.netbeans.org/topic10055-0-asc-0.html . Still unable to deploy.  Though the message says that application server is not started, from the Server tab , I am able to see a message which indicates Glassfish has started.Also , doing a netstat after trying to deploy returns this, which means that Glassfish is running.

C:>netstat -an | findstr "4848"
  TCP    0.0.0.0:4848           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING

I have been trying real hard to get this resolved. Any help is highly appreciated.

Error Message :

The Sun Java System Application Server could not start.
More information about the cause is in the Server log file.
Possible reasons include:
 - IDE timeout: refresh the server node to see if it's running now.
 - Port conflicts. (use netstat -a to detect possible port numbers already used by the operating system.)
 - Incorrect server configuration (domain.xml to be corrected manually)
 - Corrupted Deployed Applications preventing the server to start.(This can be seen in the server.log file. In this case, domain.xml needs to be modified).
 - Invalid installation location.
C:\Users\xyz\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HWebService\nbproject\build-impl.xml:564:   Deployment error:
The Sun Java System Application Server could not start.
More information about the cause is in the Server log file.
Possible reasons include:
 - IDE timeout: refresh the server node to see if it's running now.
 - Port conflicts. (use netstat -a to detect possible port numbers already used by the operating system.)
 - Incorrect server configuration (domain.xml to be corrected manually)
 - Corrupted Deployed Applications preventing the server to start.(This can be seen in the server.log file. In this case, domain.xml needs to be modified).
 - Invalid installation location.
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 29 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

I've described the solution please visit here...

http://forums.netbeans.org/post-65058.html